# VirtualBox Guest cannot access the internet

Tags: networking, virtualbox, arch-linux, manjaro

I am running Manjaro (Guest) within Windows10 (Host) where the Windows is using VPN/Proxy.

Even though my Guest VBox network setting is NAT, I am still not able to connect to the internet.

[image]

Comment: Quote from Norton "A VPN is similar to a proxy, but instead of working with single apps or websites, it works with every site you visit or app you access. Like a proxy, when you visit a website after first logging into a VPN, your IP address is hidden and replaced with the IP address of your VPN provider."   I suspect this is interfering with the virtual app NAT subsystem. Can you turn VPN OFF and try?

Comment: @John my host (Windows) is configured to use a proxy that it can only connect through VPN, so if I turn off my VPN neither the host nor the guest will be able to connect to internet. I get this error when I turn off VPN `Unable to find the proxy server`

Comment: The VPN creates a virtual network adapter on your computer. Have you defined this adapter as the one used in the guest? (Helpful [link](https://www.nakivo.com/blog/virtualbox-network-setting-guide/))

Comment: @harrymc I uploaded a SS to the question with the network adapters. I don't think the VPN created any, I am using Intel PRO/1000 MT Desktop (82540EM). Also I have tried all the adapters non worked.

Comment: I don't know what VPN you're using, but it might be `virtio-net`.

Comment: @harrymc from the link you have sent `Paravirtualized Network Adapter (virtio-net) is a special case. Instead of virtualizing networking hardware that is supported by most operating systems, a guest operating system must provide a special software interface for virtualized environments. This approach allows you to avoid the complexity of networking hardware emulating and, as a result, can improve network performance.`
So this is not created by the VPN even though I used it but again no internet access on my VM.

Comment: Which VPN are you using?

Comment: CISCO AnyConnect @harrymc

Comment: Try Bridged networking instead of NAT.

Comment: I tired this already, I could only create a bridge over laptop physical NIC(which again doesn't share my VPN), and when I chose CISCO created NIC I didn't work either. @harrymc

Comment: Can you set the router to use the VPN?

Comment: @harrymc This is a work laptop I don't have a lot of control over the laptop as same as the VPN it self, I don't have the VPN info.

Comment: So the easiest solution, running a VPN client inside the virtual machine, is impossible. Try the method in [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/533053/18736), using the "host only network".